# proof about partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let R and S be two partial orders on a set X, and T is a relation on X such that aTb(i.e. a,b ∊ X) if and only if both aRb and aSb hold. Is T also a partial order on X?
how to prove it?

Comment: Why not check each of the defining properties of a partial order to see if they hold?

Answer (score 2):

Check each of the required properties for a relation to be a partial order: reflexivity, antisymmetry, and transitivity.

Here, I go through the proof that $T$ is transitive.

---

Suppose $aTb$ and $bTc$.  We ask whether or not this implies that $aTc$ is also true.

Well... by $aTb$ we know in particular that $aRb$.  Further by $bTc$ we know in particular that $bRc$.  Since $R$ is a partial order, we know that from $aRb$ and $bRc$ and that $R$ is transitive that $aRc$ is also true.

Similarly, we can show that $aTb$ and $bTc$ imply that $aSb$ and $bSc$ from which it follows that $aSc$.

Since both $aRc$ and $aSc$ are true, it follows that $aTc$ is also true.

Thus, the relation $T$ is indeed transitive.

---

The remaining parts of the problem are just checking the other properties and they are all performed similarly.  Use what you know about how $T$ is defined in terms of $R$ and $S$ and use the fact that $R$ and $S$ are both partial orders themselves and have the desired properties.